# why 2 connections open when calling MongoClient instance in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, mongodb-java, casbah

this following code is getting mongodb connection

```
val SERVER:ServerAddress = {

val hostName=config.getString("db.hostname")

val port=config.getString("db.port").toInt
        new ServerAddress(hostName,port)
          }

val DATABASE:String   = config.getString("db.dbname")

val connectionMongo = MongoConnection(SERVER)
```

i think it should create one connection but in mongod console it shows 2 connection why is this happening

```
2016-06-24T16:20:15.412+0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-06-24T16:20:38.543+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45712 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-06-24T16:20:38.560+0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45713 #2 (2 connections now open)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MongoClient` maintains a connection pool internally.  The default size is 10, iirc, and is lazily populated.  What you're likely seeing is the driver connecting to the server to do various housekeeping work such as topology discovery.

Comment: so its ok if its accepting two connections not one when we instantiate MongoClient